# How to identify if device has in-display Biometric fingerprint support?

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api, in-display-fingerprint

I'm writing a application feature to authenticate user using [Biometric](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt.html) fingerprint authentication API. And it worked as expected with combination of [BiometricPrompt](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt.html) API.

In general it display own UI dialog so it can be unified across Android device.(Improvement from [Fingerprint Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager) API)

In one of device testing scenario I come across [in-display](https://www.androidauthority.com/how-fingerprint-scanners-work-670934/)(on screen, e.g. Oneplus 6T device) fingerprint support instead rear biometric hardware option.

When I run application on it, on call of `biometricPrompt.authenticate(..)` instead of dialog it display in-display fingerprint authentication option. Which is ok, and manage by internal API of BiometricPrompt.

But it create some inconsistency to manage for developer.

1. When it provide in-build authentication dialog, all fallback error displayed in dialog itself.
2. But in case of in-display authentication I didn't found a way where it manage to display error message it-self. And I have to handle this fallback and display in a custom way.

**Now question is**

1. Is there a way to manage/display message by in-display authentication view component.
2. How can identify if device is support in-device biometric authentication.

**Edit: Code reference I'm using:**

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import java.lang.Exception
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import javax.crypto.Cipher

class BiometricAuthenticationManager(private val context: Context) :
        BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {

    private var biometricPrompt: BiometricPrompt? = null

    override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
        super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
        biometricPrompt?.cancelAuthentication()
    }

    override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
        super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)

    }

    override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
        super.onAuthenticationFailed()
    }

    fun init(cipher: Cipher, promptInfo: BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo) {
        if (context is FragmentActivity) {
            val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

            biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(context, executor, this)
            biometricPrompt?.authenticate(promptInfo, BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject(cipher))
        } else {
            throw Exception(
                    "Check for FragmentActivity context.")
        }
    }
}
```

For further reference about how it look like, please find following attachment.

[image]

I try to check same scenario for lock screen, where I guess it uses custom implementation using FingerPrintManager class and display message.

[image]

Comment: "How can identify if device is support in-device biometric authentication" -- that seems like the wrong question. Based on your problem, the issue is not whether this is an in-screen fingerprint detector -- it is whether the error messages are handled for you. While in-screen fingerprint detectors might be more prone to this sort of problem, technically they are not connected. For example, iris scan devices might have the same problem. You might want to include a [mcve] showing your code and have screenshots depicting the difference in behaviors.

Comment: BTW, you might want to try the `androidx` edition of `BiometricPrompt` and see if it changes the behavior.

Comment: The position of the fingerprint sensor is determined by the manufacturer of the particular device. the purpose of  APIs is to authenticate the right user. so checking the in-display biometric seems not possible to me with default api.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I checked with androidX component (should actually used to support running versions below Android P) but it's not making any difference. About "if device is support in-device biometric authentication" this is the last option I'm looking for so I can put if-else when need to display errors in custom UI when it will be handle by SDK dialog component itself.

Comment: @SahilManchanda, true. But you see the issue,  when using latest Biometric API with rear sensor, it display dialog prompt which can handle error. But when using same API with in-display sensor, it does not display error message. Do you have any finding around ?

Comment: @CoDe Do you have any finding around ? A. no. will look into it today

Comment: You can use the method [BiometricManager.canAuthenticate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricManager.html#canAuthenticate())

Comment: I have a OnePlus with Android 10 and it animates the dialog. You can expect the OEM to implement error handling with e.g. haptic feedback instead of with text.

Comment: true, but for me issue is related to displaying error when it's in-display fingerprint(or when in case if it is not displaying fingerprint dialog), because in case of dialog-display sdk it self display on dialog.

Comment: @CoDe any solution to this issue?

Comment: @CosmicDev so far nothing. But you can share your usecase and I can help you to do some possible solution.

Comment: It is not displaying up in one plus 6t

Comment: Strong reason if you are using Strong Bio-metric Authentication (Using Crypto) object and you have not registered any Finger print in device Setting. I'm not sure which version of lib you are using but latest one is [androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/biometric) .

Comment: am facing similar but bit different issue with my in-screen fingerprintsensor(on my OP7T). In-case of wrong fingerprint, default implementation shows Negative Message which I had set and just waits and continue accepting fingerprints. But in case of OP7T, wrong fingerprint just produces haptic feedback(vibrate) and closes the dialog without even calling 'onAuthenticationError' and when I click back then it actually calls 'onAuthenticationError'. @CoDe are you facing similar issue.. will try to look into mine and your issue, will post if I find anything.

Comment: second scenario looks odd, but in general there is a limit of maximum wrong attempt a user can perform after that it does not allow(even any other app) to use Biometric until user lock and unlock device again. Please also note underlying layer can be modified by OEM provider (like Samsung did), so might be device specific issue.

Comment: @CoDe Its Oneplus's Oxygen OS buggy implementation. check pommytom's answer on OnePlus forum he has explained it quite nicely and have also mentioned some workaround: https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/oneplus-7-pro-fingerprint-biometricprompt-does-not-show.1035821/   as far as i suggest you can show Toast onAuthenticationFailed() it won't be same as LockScreen failure response but it can consider and workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Faced with the same problem some time ago - OnePlus 6T has no Biometric UI, at the same time Samsung A51 - has its own (custom) UI for Fingerprint API and another for BiometricPrompt API.
I tried to watch for Activity window focus loss (For OnePlus - activity do not lose focus, at the same time BiometricPrompt UI leads to focus loss), but appear a problem with the Samsung device.

The only solution that I found, and it works for now:

1. Need to get the correct device name (for OnePlus for example, it should be not **ONEPLUS A6003**, but **One Plus 6** instead)
2. Need to perform request to `https://m.gsmarena.com/res.php3?sSearch=Device+Name`, you should get the list with matches, usually, first one is needed
3. Parse HTML (from previews step) to get the link for device specification (like `https://m.gsmarena.com/oneplus_6t-9350.php`)
4. Now you need to perform a request to this link and again parse HTML and get the "**Sensors**" section. You should get a string like "**Fingerprint (under display, optical), accelerometer, gyro, proximity, compass**"
5. Split this string to get the list with sensors
6. Now when you need to check if an in-display scanner is present on the device, just check for "**fingerprint**" and "**under display**" for the same sensor.

[Link](https://github.com/Salat-Cx65/AdvancedBiometricPromptCompat/blob/main/biometric/src/main/java/dev/skomlach/biometric/compat/utils/device/DeviceInfoManager.kt) with impl. that can be used as an example

Comment: Well explained. I'll see some time to try this and thanks for sample repo.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    //Fingerprint API only available on from Android 6.0 (M)
    FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
    if (!fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()) { 
        // Device doesn't support fingerprint authentication     
    } else if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) { 
        // User hasn't enrolled any fingerprints to authenticate with 
    } else { 
        // Everything is ready for fingerprint authentication 
    }
}
```

Dont Forget to Add

```
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. The question isn't how to check if fingerprint authentication is supported; it's to check whether or not the fingerprint sensor is located in the display (as opposed to somewhere else, like the back of the device).

Comment: @Vijay, the Question is about, identify if the device has in-display Biometric fingerprint support or not. Please improve your answer